# Is equal length of primes in Paillier cryptosystem is mandate for security reasons?

Tags: paillier

In continuation to [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19056/equal-length-of-primes-in-paillier-cryptosystem) question about length of primes , I am in doubt about the restriction on length of primes itself .

In Paillier  cryptosystem , equal length of primes are used .

My doubt is whether this restriction is to ensure the following [condition](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18058/choosing-primes-in-the-paillier-cryptosystem) only

$$\gcd(pq,(p-1)(q-1))=1$$

or , there are another security reasons that makes the equal length condition mandate .

I mean, in cryptosystems like RSA, approximately equal length primes are generally preferred for security reasons , If the length is more than specified value, then cryptosystem is not secure.

Is it the same case in paillier cryptosysyem too or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, *exactly equal* length of primes $p$ and $q$ is not mandatory for security (or proper functioning) in the [Pailler cryptosystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paillier_cryptosystem). Sufficient requirements are that $p$ and $q$ are prime, $N=p q$ is hard to factor, and $\gcd(p q,(p-1)(q-1))=1$.

The requirement that $p$ and $q$ are of *exactly equal* size is usually made in the Pailler cryptosystem because this requirement

- implies that $p<2q<4p$, which implies $\gcd(p q,(p-1)(q-1))=1$, which is a must for the Pailler cryptosystem to work;
- is customary in RSA, and thus is an easily met condition, and unobjectionable from a security standpoint;
- is a consequence of stronger conditions mandated by [FIPS 186-4](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf) and the earlier ANSI X9.31 RSA key generation standards, which both require $2^{k-1/2}<p<2^k$ and $2^{k-1/2}<q<2^k$ for integer $k$ at least 512 (and further constrained, including to be a multiple of 64), because it simplifies implementations of RSA, including using the [CRT method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm); and similar implementation considerations apply to the Pailler cryptosystem.

More precisely, on security:

- even though imposing that $p$ and $q$ are of *exactly equal* size does reduce the choices for $N$, and thus helps at least some factorization algorithms (notably [Fermat's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_factorization_method) and derivatives), it would be a surprise if such algorithms could be extended to factor with odds $\epsilon$ and expected cost lower than $\epsilon\min(p,q)^u$ operations, where $u\approx2/5$ in our wildest dreams, and even $u\approx1/2$ is hard to reach; thus such algorithms are not to fear in the first place, for they do not have odds worth consideration to factor products of two randomly-generated primes of *approximately equal* size if that size makes factorization by [GNFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) hard enough; says $N$ at least 768-bit (the [current academic record](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/006)), thus $\min(p,q)$ at least 350-bit, making $\min(p,q)^{2/5}$ at least 140-bit.
- on the contrary, that $p$ and $q$ are of *exactly equal* size slightly increases the expected time to factor $N$ by the sub-exponential [ECM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic_curve_factorization) for a given size of $N$, and does not lower the expected cost of any other sub-exponential algorithm that we know; thus can be regarded as more beneficial than not from a security standpoint.